# for(Something s : something.getList())

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have quick question
Does it matter if I use clause this way :

```
for(Object obj : something.b.c.d.getList(){
...
}
```

or this

```
List list = something.b.c.d.getList();
for(Object obj : list){
...
}
```

I'm wondering if one is faster than other

Comment: It seems you're concerned about performance micro-optimizations, but such code shows you really should concerned about design and type-safety: it uses a raw list instead of a generic list, and uses public fields instead of accessors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is stylistic. The semantics are pretty much the same. The only significant semantic difference is that, in the second example, the list reference is named and can be accessed both inside and after the loop:

```
List list = something.b.c.d.getList();
for(Object obj : list){
   if (list.contains(...)) { // inefficient, used purely as an illustration
      ...
   }
}
int n = list.size();
```

The above cannot be achieved in the first example without evaluating `something.b.c.d.getList()` again.

If you are concerned that the first example repeatedly evaluates `something.b.c.d.getList()`, that's certainly not the case. Both of your examples evaluate the expression exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

There's likely no difference in performance, but performance overall would depend on how expensive it is to access those fields (i.e. lazy loading from a framework).  Accessing the fields would only happen once, regardless of whichever style you chose to use for this loop.

Both approaches are acceptable if both items are something that can be used in the enhanced-for statement.

I wouldn't concern myself with optimizations like this unless a profiler designated this particular area of your code as a trouble spot.

Comment: I don't follow the argument. Surely the fields are only accessed once?

Comment: You're probably right about that.  I may have been reading it a bit too fast.  Let me rephrase it a bit.

Comment: I have no evidence to prove it, but to me it is just synctatic sugar, both approaches compile into the same code, which is : `Iterator<Object> it = list.iterator(); while (it.hasNext()) { ... }`

Comment: @Dici:  That's right.  I had to re-read the JLS for a refresher, but yes, they do essentially become the same expression.

Comment: I suggest you delete this answer then, as it *implies* that `getList()` will be called multiple times.

Comment: @JonSkeet:  How does it imply that?  I've reworded my question since my original statement.

Comment: @Makato: the part about it mattering how expensive it is to access the fields, which implies (imo) that the expression will be evaluated multiple times.

Comment: I can rephrase that to make it seem less like that's the case, then.

Comment: It seems, that this answer depends on context of the previous one. Cost of accessing the fields of `something` does make sense only in case we will need to use the `list` *again* in body of the loop. @Makato, you ought  to provide some code example to illustrate what are you talking about exactly.